# I need to validate form data using JQuery before i can post it using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my form that i created using `HTML` and `Bootstrap`

```
<div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
  <form id="frm-post-comment" name="frm-post-comment" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="the-comment" value="true">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <button id="comment-post" class="btn btn-info pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I then want to validate the form inputs using `JQuery`, here is the *validation code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comment-post").click(function() {
    submitComment();
    $("#comment-pst-alert").show();
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
  });
});

function submitComment() {
  var msg = "";
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var comments = $("#comments").val();
  var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

  if (name == "" || name.length < 3) {
    msg += "*Please enter a valid name,it must be longer than three characters.<br>";
  }

  if (!re.test(name)) {
    msg += "*Please enter a valid name,it must not contain numbers.";
  }

  var chkEmail = /^[a-z0-9._%-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

  if (email == "") {
    msg += "<br>*Please enter an email address.";
  }

  if (email.length < 8) {
    msg += "<br>*Email address cannot be less than 8 characters";
  }

  if (email.search('@') == -1) {
    msg += "<br>*Email must have a @,please enter a valid email address.";
  }

  if (comments == "") {
    msg += "<br>*Please enter a comment.";
  }

  if (comments.length > 70) {
    msg += "<br>*The comment can not exceed 70 characters";
  }

  if (msg != "") {
    $("#comment-pst-alert").addClass("alert-danger");
    $("#comment-pst-alert").children("strong").text("Warning");
    $("#comment-pst-alert").children("p").html(msg);
  } 
  else {
    $("#name").val("");
    $("#email").val("");
    $("#comments").val("");

    var closeAlert = $("<a/>", {
      "class": "close",
      "data-dismiss": "alert",
      "text": "x"
    });

    $("#comment-pst-alert strong").before(closeAlert);
    $("#comment-pst-alert").removeClass("alert-danger");
    $("#comment-pst-alert").addClass("alert-success");
    $("#comment-pst-alert").children("strong").text("Success");
    msg += "<br>You have successfully submitted your details, you will      here from us within 24 hours.";
    $("#comment-pst-alert").children("p").html(msg);
  }

  $("#comment-pst-alert").show();
}
```

I have a `bootstrap alert control` that is initially hidden using `CSS`. If there is an *error* in the user input, I show the alert control and add the `relevant class` to it. If there is no error, I want to *remove the former class* and add a `success class` to the alert control and then I want to submit the input and add the data into the database using `PHP`.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

if ($connection) {
  if ($_POST["name"] != "" || 
      $_POST["email"] != "" || 
      $_POST["comments"] != "") {
    mysql_select_db("smart_hustle_comments") or die("could not select table ".mysql_error());
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $comment = $_POST["comments"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES('$name','$email','$comment')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
  }
}
```

I am getting *no error on console nor on PHP*,the form submits but does not execute the `JQuery` validation, please help.

Comment: I realized that i am using the id tag in my JQuery but i do not have the input id's in my HTML ,it wasn't working even when i had the id's on the HTML inputs, i tried using hidden controls with id's that will point to the input controls using PHP like <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']?>">

Comment: Change `type="button"` and use `event.preventDefault()` before  `submitComment();` in `click`. and if it get validate success then do `$('#frm-post-comment').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery validation is skipped because you submit form simultaneously with validation.
Change your button type to `button` type instead `submit`, after successfull validation use `$('#frm-post-comment').submit();` to apply form.

Comment: Where should i use the $('#frm-post-comment').submit();?,within the on click event of the button or on document.ready()?

Comment: @Ambrose after successfull validation, in this case in last else statment i think

Comment: I have amended the script but it does not insert the data into the database instead it brings the following value-pairs on the url( http://localhost/smartHustle/index.php?the-comment=true&name=SDC&email=SDC@ASD&comments=SDCSDC# ),but i am using the POST method

Comment: @Ambrose jquery have to only pass data to your server (via post in your case), try to dump your post data with var_dump($_POST); die(); and see if data is even arrived

Comment: Hello i have used the var_dump function in PHP,it returns this    array(4) {
  ["the-comment"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comments"]=>
  string(0)